# What kind of bluetooth communication method should I use contact with third party application?

Tags: nrf52, nrf-connect

I am using nRF5340 and am totaly newbee at nRF environment as well as ble. There is an example shared by nRF that allows send data that received from BL over UART and vice versa. This example is working with nRF connect BL serial port emulator and other 3rd party tool but my goal is connecting to 3rd party applications that can send positioning data over Bluetooth. However, My device is not connecting to these applications with this example. Is BL serial correct way ? Do I have to add something to code ? Modifying these apps is not possible btw.
I am open to any suggestion from anyone who got familiar with nRF5340 or nRF environment.

I need a GNNS app to get positioning data to send my nRF5340 custom board via Bluetooth. So, I used peripheral_uart example. My goal is to send data I received from BL to my another MCU in the board. I tested this code snippet with nRF's own BL serial terminal and it is working, also tested 3th party BL Seril Port app that can regocnize nRF devices. But could not manage to communicate with other GNSS BL applications on the market.

Comment: Can you give us more information about th third party application? Is it using BLE or Bluetooth Classic/Serial? I'm asking because the nRF5340 [does not support Bluetooth Classic](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/92169/bluetooth-classic-hardware-support)

Comment: Hello, the app is http://lefebure.com/software/android-ntripclient/

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. Is this the app you want to use with your nRF5340? And it is not working? Which app did you use to get it to work?

Comment: Hello, the app is http://lefebure.com/software/android-ntripclient/ 
and they stated they support SPP for bluetooth which is not suitable for BLE. On the other hand in the application there is bluetooth connection method such as BLE, Insecure (Default), Secure, Secure via Reflection, Insecure via Reflection.  I picked BLE but did not work also.  
Let me clear one more thing, if I find an app that support BLE communication really, does this means my nRF5340 talk with it ? I suspecting of nRF NUS (Nordic Uart Service ) is kind of custom service and may not be recognise by most of devices ?

Comment: @Michael Kotzjan sorry for miss-communication. I updated my question and told the story and goals.

Comment: The app looks for a Bluetooth Classic device using the Serial Port Profile (SPP). As you already stated, SPP is not supported by BLE. I don't know what the different methods mean you found in the app. My best guess would be that the nRF5340 is not the right platform for your application. Regarding your question about the NUS: All BLE devices offer the services they provide, it is up to the application to use them correctly. The NUS is not a standard service, it's a service by nordic. But there is no default service for gps data.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Oh! How my device would talk with other BLE devices then ? What is our options? If NUS is a custom service, only way to do this is making our own app ? If yes, how can I design a BLE app that would be compatible with NUS ? I am trying find the minimum affort btw.

Comment: Your device can communicate with other BLE devices using services and characteristic. It totally depends on which service you choose if you control both devices or the ones the other device offers. It should be in the documentation if the device offers one. Yes, you can design your own app. NUS is pretty well [documented](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v14.0.0%2Fble_sdk_app_nus_eval.html). You only have two characteristics, one to read from and one to write to

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Bad suprise. Thanks Michael for the help.